# How to loop a function for a period of time

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

Trying to loop a function for a specific period of time, bear in mind the function takes about 20 seconds to finish executing.

There's obviously the option of using something along the lines of:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long length = 30000;
while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= length){
  foo(); // takes 20 seconds to finish executing
}
```

the only flaw with this is, if foo takes 20 seconds to run, this code will not interrupt at 30, and will loop for another 20 seconds before while is false, hence execute for 40 seconds.

foo is this code snippet:

```
new SequenceStrategy(NUMBER_FAIRY_LIGHTS, colours).runLightsAlgorithm();

public class SequenceStrategy implements LightsStrategy {
    private List<Light> fairyLightsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SequenceStrategy(int numFairyLights, String[] colours) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numFairyLights; i += colours.length) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colours.length && i + j < numFairyLights; j++) {
                fairyLightsList.add(new Light(colours[j], OFF_STATUS, i + j));
            }
        }
    }

    public void runLightsAlgorithm() {
        for (int i = 0; i < fairyLightsList.size(); i++) {
            lightUtilsObject.outputLightMessage(fairyLightsList.get(i).getLightIndex() + 1, fairyLightsList.get(i).getLightColour(), ON_STATUS);
            //Thread sleep for 0.5 second after toggling light in sequence
            lightUtilsObject.lightToggleWait(500);
            lightUtilsObject.outputLightMessage(i + 1, fairyLightsList.get(i).getLightColour(), OFF_STATUS);
            lightUtilsObject.lightToggleWait(500);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What's inside `foo()`?

Comment: Please make your question much less theoretical and much more concrete.

Comment: Sorry guys this is my first post, so will get better with content in time.
Anyways foo() is some code that includes Thread.sleep(), and overall takes about 20 second to run.

Comment: Since you know that foo(); takes 20 seconds to run, you might be able to do length - 20000, that way foo() will start at say 10 seconds, and end at 30 seconds. May not be the best solution, but should work given that foo() is exactly 20 seconds. (There's probably a better solution)

Comment: Like shmosel and Hovercraft, I'm also having a hard time understanding what you want. Could you be more specific on what you're trying to achive? Can't you simply put a conditional inside foo and `return` if you want it to stop if condition is not fulfilled?

Comment: i've just added relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Use java [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Below is a simple demo that has a function which takes 20 seconds to finish but due to timer limit of 30 seconds it cancels the execution on second run.

```
package javaPractice;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Timer task started at:"+new Date());
        completeTask();
        System.out.println("Timer task finished at:"+new Date());
    }

    private void completeTask() {
        try {
            //assuming it takes 20 secs to complete the task
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        //running timer task as daemon thread
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 10*1000);
        System.out.println("TimerTask started");
        //cancel after sometime
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("TimerTask cancelled");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

[Refrence](https://www.journaldev.com/1050/java-timer-timertask-example)